How to fill the null values within certain time range and gnerate a reasonable data curve trend in Apache IoTDB?
I would like to ask if it is possible to exclude null values by executing group by ([1698681600000,1698710717000), 5m, 5m) query statement in Apache IoTDB. I know that IoTDB can generate fill to switch the null values to not-null values, but when I fill the null value with an impossible data value, then the curve I generated by these data became obviously uncoordinated. I want to know how can I simultaneously achieve filling null values and generate a reasonable curve?

Please provide a [mre] with sample data and desired results.

You can add fill (linear) at the end of the Apache IoTDB query statement, which means filling the column with a linear interpolation of the previous non-null value and the next non-null value of the column. This way your results and your graph will both be coordinated.
